# How to fix VLC not recognizing the input format from YouTube Lens?

Tags: vlc, lenses, youtube, scopes

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and VLC 1.1.12.  When I click on a video result in the lens, it opens VLC and I get the following error:

```
VLC can't recognize the input's format:
The format of 'http://www.youtube.com/v/t4H_Zoh7G5A' cannot be detected. Have a look at the log for details.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please add that as an answer instead, and accept it. That way, when people encounter a similar issue, they can search for the question and see that it is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

(converted OP answer in question to answer)

I actually just found the answer to my own question. I updated to VLC version 2.0 and it now works correctly. Here are the details:

For the current stable version of VLC that is `ppa:videolan/stable-daily` (currently version 2.0)

Add it to your system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

Update and upgrade / install VLC:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Hope this helps anyone else who has been experiencing this problem.